# How can I register my mobile app with FitBit to use it's API if my mobile app needs FitBit API to be developed?

Tags: api, mobile, fitbit

I am new to developing mobile applications. I want to develop a mobile app that reads data from a FitBit watch and does something with that data. After searching on the Internet and on dev.fitbit.com I must register my application so that I can use it's API by providing the required information such as where the application can be downloaded, what the callback URL is. Sounds like the application needs to be done first before it can use FitBit API. But how can I develop my mobile application without its API? I really don't understand this concept. Can someone help me find the answer?

Answer (score 1):

For getting data you must first register your app on fitbit. 
 You dont't need to create your application first what you are trying to build.
 To register your app, it needs some basic information about your app like Application Name, Description etc.

Provide these information about your app. After registerting, fitbit will provide you some tokens (clientId, clientSecret etc). Using these tokens(using OAuth2.0), you will get access token. Using this access token you can fetch data from fitbit and start building your app.

While registerinh your app you need to provide the following details.

Application Name : Predefined Name of your app that you are building. This will shown as explained.

Suppose you want to create account on http://stackoverflow.com. If you have already an account on gmail or facebook, you can sign up with google or facebook.
Suppose you sign up with google, after providing your google credentials, one popup will come like this:

"Stack Exchange would like to" 
asking some permission to access google profile information.
Here in place of stack exchange your app name will be visible.

Description : some description about your app.

Application Website : base address of your site. 
like https://www.gmail.com/

Organization: name of your organization.

Organization Website: your org web site

OAuth 2.0 Application Type: use client

Callback URL: this is predefined rest api. that will be used for token generation during oauth flow. after successful authorization,you will return to callback url.

Default Access Type: Give read id only want to read the information.

Comment: I do understand this. But can you explain me a little bit more like if I have not created an application yet, how can I enter where the app can be downloaded and what the callback URL is? Should it be a pre defined information?